# Removing spaces at a certain position in a string

Tags: java

My input string has a value of `4BI C 06W 045  PNL 02 E` and I would like the output to be `4BI C 06W 045  PNL02E`

**Input**  :

```
4BI C 06W 045  PNL 02 E
```

**output** :

```
4BI C 06W 045  PNL02E (removing spaces in between PNL ,02 and E).
```

Thanks
Pavan

Comment: is `PNL ,02 and E)` a fixed format with same characters/alphabets

Comment: And what have you tried so far?

Comment: @ankur-singhal yes its a fixed format with the same format

Comment: Can you show us what you've tried thus far, that way we won't say things you've already tried... people usually post the code they've already used or attempted to use, and any relevant code to the project... please take the tour: http://stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: @user3189142 i tried substring of last characters tried with trim and concat both however trim is not removing spaces.

Comment: @pawankumar i hope format is fixed, considering that i posted an answer

Comment: `String s1="4BI C 06W 045  PNL 02 E";
  String s4=s1.substring(0,14);
  String s2=s1.substring(15);
  String s3=s2.replaceAll("\\s+","");
  
  String s5=s4+s3;
  System.out.println("desire string--"+s5);`

Comment: @BhargavModi i think your solution will also work but i did not try

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
        String LCName = "4BI C 06W 045  PNL 02 E";
        String first = LCName.split("  ")[0] + " ";
        String second = LCName.split("  ")[1].replaceAll("\\s+", "");
        System.out.println(first.concat(second));
    }
```

**Output**

```
4BI C 06W 045 PNL02E
```

Comment: Fantastic.I just tried in SAP NWDS and it works for all values dynamically.I am not a Java expert and know very minimal java.

Answer (score 0):

I'd try it with a RegEx

I'm not familiar with Java but according to http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html the `\s` regex exists.

So A simple regex could be something like `\s{2,}` or with slashes to indicate the start and ending `/ \s{2,}/` this will get you all double whitespaces. You then simply have to replace it with a single whitespace.

Edit: It seams that you'd have to escape a backslash too in Java so use `\\s{2,}` as your regex (http://ocpsoft.org/opensource/guide-to-regular-expressions-in-java-part-1/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
String in = "4BI C 06W 045  PNL 02 E";
in = in.split("  ")[0] + "  " + in.split("  ")[1].replace(" ","");
```

I tested, and it works for me.

Comment: I think this will result in `4BIC`?

Answer (score -1):

```
String s = "DSD SDFS PNL  02   E";
s = s.replaceAll("PNL\\s*02\\s*E", "PNL02E");
System.out.println(s);
```

Comment: Are you sure he will always have this specific string?

Comment: its not the fixed string i just mention the format.it can be like 4BI C 06W 045  PNL 02 E,4BI C 06W 045  PNL 03 E,4BI C 06W 045  PNL 03 W and so on....

Comment: so you just want PNL 00(two numbers) X(one letter) to be PNL00X  ?